# Struggles with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a relatively simple web page with forms using php. I've simplified it for this so it may be easier to explain. I have my variables in php, as shown here:

```
<?php
$thing =(isset($_GET['thing'])) ? $_GET['thing']:"";
echo "<td><button onclick = theFunc()>Confirm</td>\n";
?>
```

As you can see, I call a function, which is written in JavaScript, defined as follows:

```
function theFunc(){
        window.location = "www.url.com?thing=$thing";
        var thing = "<?php echo $thing; ?>";
}
```

I got the second line within the function online. Now, when I click the submit button, I have it take me to a new php page, where I have only asked it to echo the value within the variable for the time being. It is below:

```
<?php
    $thing = $_GET["thing"];
    echo "$thing";
?>
```

Although I cannot seem to get it to actually carry over the value. Am I being very stupid and forgetting a key part of the transition? All it prints out is '$thing', not the value. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For starters, `var thing` is discarded. You probably want `window.location = "www.url.com?thing=<?= $thing ?>";` There's no form anywhere in your code though, and your approach seems awkward. What is your goal? Having the user enter something on a form on page A, then display something based on that on page B? That's *much* easier.

Comment: `window.location = "www.url.com?thing=<?php echo $thing; ?>";` - you are in javascript context there, so no php would be executed, unless you tell php (apache) to do so with `<?php...`

Comment: you could simplify that in just doing `echo "<td><a href='www.url.com?thing=$thing'>Confirm</a></td>\n";` (and style that link as a button)

Comment: I think maybe in JavaScript you need to put `${thing}` in your JavaScript and also move the declaration of the `thing`  before  the `window.location’ line. Maybe I’m misunderstanding.

Comment: Yeah I didnt add the form as didnt believe it would be necessary. Thats what I am trying to do to some degree, just trying to figure out how to carry variables from page A to page B

Comment: Are you aware that your `button` doesn't have a closing tag? :)

Comment: @JohnSmith Using a form is the default way, the cleanest solution. Only if you need special behavior should you resort to adding JS into the mix. See my answer for the basic solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very basic from processing in PHP:

Some page, like `index.php`:

```
<form action="processform.php" method="GET">
  <input name="thing">
  <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

And now you need `processform.php`:

```
<?php
  $thing = $_GET["thing"];
  echo $thing;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, I had tried similar things before but it turns out the issue I was having was that I had the input type as a button as opposed to a submit. This wouldnt let me proceed to the next page. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

First, pleas write your code completely but in your function

```
$thing
```

in url isn't valid.

```
 function theFunc(){
    window.location = "www.url.com?thing=<?php echo $thing; ?>";
    var thing = "<?php echo $thing; ?>";
  }
```